# Change the color of a variable in draw string function

Tags: java, graphics

I am using the Graphics to draw a string to the monitor and i want that a specific variable wiil be in a diffrent color.

e.g: "You hit by a meteor " + number + " times. 
I want the "number" will draw in different color from the string. Maybe i can work with HTML?

Comment: can you provide a minimal running example - this will help to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With Graphics you have a    drawString(String str, int x, int y) for drawing strings. Since its using the graphics context's current font and color, all you can do is something like this:

```
g.setColor();
g.drawString();
g.setColor();
g.drawString();
```

... and so on. In your case drawing it in 3 pieces.